# how to set alarm for notification in two different time together in android

Tags: android, service

I had created an app where user can select checkin and checkout time and i want to show a statusbar notification on both the times to the user even if the app is closed.

I used service to trigger the notification on time and notification is showed when i call them individually but when i set alarm for both together out notification pops only at checkout time but saying it as checkin time. I couldn't figure out the reason.

My class where i bind service

```
    checkin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            currentHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            currentMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(Reservation.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minutes) {
                    selectedhour=hourOfDay;
                    selectedminute=minutes;
                    if (hourOfDay >= 12) {
                        amPm = "PM";
                    } else {
                        amPm = "AM";
                    }
                    checkin.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", hourOfDay, minutes) + amPm);
                }
            }, currentHour, currentMinute, false);

            timePickerDialog.show();

        }
    });
    checkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            currentHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            currentMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(Reservation.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minutes) {
                    selectedcouthour=hourOfDay;
                    selectedcoutmin=minutes;
                    if (hourOfDay >= 12) {
                        amPm = "PM";
                    } else {
                        amPm = "AM";
                    }
                    checkout.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", hourOfDay, minutes) + amPm);
                }
            }, currentHour, currentMinute, false);

            timePickerDialog.show();

        }
    });
  .....
  private void setnotification() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int thisYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    Log.d("nn", "# thisYear : " + thisYear);

    int thisMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    Log.d("nn", "@ thisMonth : " + thisMonth);

    int thisDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    Log.d("nn", "$ thisDay : " + thisDay);
   // Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(thisYear, thisMonth, thisDay);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedhour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedminute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();

    int thisYear1 = calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    Log.d("nn", "# thisYear : " + thisYear);

    int thisMonth1 = calendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    Log.d("nn", "@ thisMonth : " + thisMonth);

    int thisDay1 = calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    Log.d("nn", "$ thisDay : " + thisDay);
    // Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.set(thisYear, thisMonth, thisDay);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedcouthour);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedcoutmin);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    //Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Ask our service to set an alarm for that date, this activity talks to the client that talks to the service
    scheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(calendar,"Checkin");
    scheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(calendar1, "Checkout");
```

my service class that pops notification

```
 public class NotifyService extends Service {
NotificationManager manager;
Notification myNotication;
String status;
//Button Start;
NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
PendingIntent pIntent;
//NotificationManager manager;
Intent resultIntent;
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder;

/**
 * Class for clients to access
 */
public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
    NotifyService getService() {
        return NotifyService.this;
    }
}

// Unique id to identify the notification.
private static final int NOTIFICATION = 123;
// Name of an intent extra we can use to identify if this service was started to create a notification
public static final String INTENT_NOTIFY = "com.example.smartpark.service.INTENT_NOTIFY";
// The system notification manager
private NotificationManager mNM;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i("NotifyService", "onCreate()");
    //mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
   status=intent.getStringExtra("status");
    // If this service was started by out AlarmTask intent then we want to show our notification
    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_NOTIFY, false)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"not",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        showNotification();
    }
    // We don't care if this service is stopped as we have already delivered our notification
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

// This is the object that receives interactions from clients
private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();

/**
 * Creates a notification and shows it in the OS drag-down status bar
 */
private void showNotification() {
    // This is the 'title' of the notification
   /*CharSequence title = "Alarm!!";
    // This is the icon to use on the notification
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert;
    // This is the scrolling text of the notification
    CharSequence text = "Your notification time is upon us.";
    // What time to show on the notification
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, text, time);

    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, Reservation.class), 0);

    // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent);

    // Clear the notification when it is pressed
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Send the notification to the system.
    mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);

    // Stop the service when we are finished
    stopSelf();
} */
  /*  notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    //Title for Notification
    notification.setContentTitle("Learn2Crack Updates");
    //Message in the Notification
    notification.setContentText("New Post on Android Notification.");
    //Alert shown when Notification is received
    notification.setTicker("New Message Alert!");
    //Icon to be set on Notification
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_overlay);
    //Creating new Stack Builder
    stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(Reservation.class);
    //Intent which is opened when notification is clicked
    resultIntent = new Intent(this, Reservation.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    pIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setContentIntent(pIntent);
    manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, notification.build());


}*/
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.smartpark.Reservation");

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, 0);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);

    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.setTicker("this is ticker text");
    builder.setContentTitle("Alert from Smartpark");
    builder.setContentText("Your  "+status+" time is just reached");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_overlay);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setOngoing(true);
    builder.setSubText("Time Alert...");   //API level 16
    builder.setNumber(100);
    Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    builder.setSound(uri);
    builder.build();

    myNotication = builder.getNotification();
    myNotication.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    manager.notify(11, myNotication);
}
```

i expect the notification to pop up exactly on correct time with correct context.